# Will swift 4 supports the external libraries?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I am thinking to update my app written in swift 3 to swift 4 and here I used objective c external libraries which needed in my app and the same objective c files will supports for swift 4 or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjC is supported by all Swift versions.

But, as are surely using a version control system for your code (as every sane developer does) you can just try it. If it doesn't work, check out the version before the migration.

Comment: what is version control system and how to use it ?

Comment: git for example is a version control system. There are tons of informations about git in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,surely it would work since objective C library wont have any effect if the swift version is modified.Both swift and objective c are interoperable as written in apple documentation so it should work